# Pasar un array dinámico por parámetro a una función

Tags: c

Declare el siguiente arreglo dinamico sin tamaño aun

```
 int * a;///ARREGLO DINAMICO LLAMADO A
```

El tamaño se lo defino en el siguiente paso, la variable pares vale 4 en este caso

```
a = (int *)malloc(pares*sizeof(int));
```

A la hora de pasar el arreglo dinamico por parametro a una funcion, el compilador me tira eror, en que me equivoco?

```
void pasajeDePares (int arreglos[], int v,int *a)
```

Comment: Podrías subir todo lo que llevas de código para verificar su estructura

Comment: ¿Cómo invocas la función? ¿Cómo pasas los valores? Falta detalles en esa pregunta para poder ayudar. Y también hay un error de concepto. Lo que declaraste no es un arreglo dinámico, sino, un puntero. Por lo tanto, `a` es un puntero a `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Marca error porque en tu función tienes dos parametros definidos con el nombre `a`, aqui deje un ejemplo de como funciona el paso de punteros por si acaso

```
void view(int *a, int n){
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%i",a[i]);
}

int main(){
    int *a = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    a[0] = 1, a[1] = 2, a[2] = 3, a[3] = 4;

    view(a, 4);

    return 0;
}//SALIDA: 1234
```

Comment: Cambie el nombre del parametro pero sigue sin funcionar